# SignalR Fails with more than 2 connections

Tags: websocket, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have written a fairly simple chat application in SignalR.

It seems if i connect with more than 2 tabs/browsers/devices the third will hang and never connect and eventually cause problems.

Why can I only connect with 2 users?

The third request goes through as soon as I disconnect one of the other 2.

Doesn't matter if I use the same user or different users.

I am using IIS on Windows 10, Asp.Net MVC5 with SignalR 2.2

It never calls the hub code, if I try to connect with a fourth client while that tab is open the fourth tab won't even return the view. 
[image: This is the client side logging.]

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //add all existing messages when we start the connection
    //chat.server.addExistingMessages();
    console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
```

console.log is never hit for the third connection.

```
$.connection.hub.start()
```

Is hit, and the connection and hub have values that aren't null.

```
  public override Task OnConnected()
    {
```

Is never hit on the third connection unless I terminate one of the other two. So sharing the internals of these methods/functions would only add confusion I feel.

```
$.connection.hub.starting(function () {
    console.log('starting')
});
$.connection.hub.received(function () {
    console.log('connection received')
});
```

On the third client, starting his put in the console but received isn't.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the code. Thanks!

Comment: What bit is pertinent? Just the on connect? The entire hub?  Hub + js?

Comment: My hub onConnected isn't even being hit until I close the browser

Comment: Also I can connect to the asp.net home page with as many users as I want, it's just the chatHub(signalr) part.

Comment: anything `static` in the C# code?

Comment: I have two static concurrent dictionaries but I tried making them not static and it still didn't work.

Comment: So i copied all the code I added, all the classes i added etc over to a new project. It worked up until the point that I put it on IIS instead of IIS Express, so what is different about IIS than IIS Express that would only allow 2 connections to the chat portion? I can have several more when connecting to just the home page.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if the third application is on a different application running on IIS(The clone I made) it will also get rejected. So I can only have 2 connections even if they are different applications. Why is websockets hanging in start only on IIS though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I was able to discover the answer to this after much hair pulling out and frustration.

Because desktop IIS only allows 10 concurrent connections and websocket connections are so dynamic I think that it was acting as 10 connections with only 2 actual connections.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

> "full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will
>   be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be
>   reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently
>   re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being
>   used. IIS Express should be used on client operating systems."

**If that is not the case then someone please correct me!**

As a work around I am going to use IIS Express, my reasoning behind not wanting to was becauase I wanted my site exposed so my co-workers could connect and sanity test. I figured out how to expose IIS to the web and run it from a command prompt so I can develop while the server is up.
 [This is how to expose IIS Express](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)
Go to
c:\Users[YourName]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

Add(replacing IP address and port appropriately):

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58938:192.168.1.42" />
```

To the relevant site.

[Running IIS from command line](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)

> Open a command prompt.
>
> You do not need Administrator user rights to run the commands in this
>   walkthrough. However, you must have Administrator user rights if you
>   want to run IIS Express on ports numbered 1024 or less. Run the
>   following command to navigate to the IIS Express installation folder:

```
cd \Program Files\IIS Express
```

> or if you are using a 64-bit OS, run the
>   following command: cd \Program Files (x86)\IIS Express Run the
>   following command to view the IIS Express usage string:

```
iisexpress /site:site-name
```

and of course don't forget about port forwarding and firewall pass through.